# async for in function def in event or command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to reduce my code in bot and my first try with it end with:

```
<coroutine object logi_member_role_update.<locals>.logi_role_by at 0x000001D202E20A40>
C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:343: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'logi_member_role_update.<locals>.logi_role_by' was never awaited
  await coro(*args, **kwargs)
```

Code:

```
def logi_member_role_update(before):
    async def logi_role_by(before):
        async for author in before.guild.audit_logs(limit = 1, oldest_first = False, action = discord.AuditLogAction.member_role_update):
            return '{0.user.id}'.format(author)
    return logi_role_by(before)

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    e = discord.Embed(color = client.get_user(id_arnoldzika).color, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
    e.set_thumbnail(url = before.avatar_url)
    if before.roles != after.roles:
        member = logi_member_role_update(before)
        print(member)
```

And my question is: what was left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output pretty much speaks for itself - coroutines are supposed to be awaited

```py
member = await logi_member_role_update(before)
```

Also I'm unsure why you're wrapping the `logi_role_by` function, you could simply do

```py
async def logi_member_update(before):
    async for author in before.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, oldest_first=False, action=discord.AuditLogAction.member_role_update):
        return '{0.user.id}'.format(author)


# In the event
member = await logi_member_role_update(before)
```